# How do I reinstall shared dependencies after upgrade to 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, dependencies, emacs

I just upgraded to 16.04.  When I tried to launch Emacs from the command line, I get the following error

```
emacs/src/emacs: error while loading shared libraries: libgif.so.4: 
cannot open  shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I run ldd it tells me the following two dependencies are not found:

```
libgif.so.4 => not found
libgnutls-deb0.so.28 => not found
```

I tried apt-get installing libgif7 but it tells me that's already there and up-to-date. I'm not really sure how else to begin tackling this.

How do I reinstall these dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact same problem after the 16.04 upgrade.

The thing is that I had emacs built from source, so I solved it by: re-downloading the source package, compiling & re-installing.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Installing-Emacs.html for specific instructions.

Hope it helps.